# Incorrect Syntax error near @BranchID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create the SP with two temporary table . But I get the error '**Incorrect Syntax Error**'

The Store Procedure that I created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Compare]
(                  
 @BranchID INT,                  
 @FromDate DATE,                    
 @ToDate DATE,                  
 @FromDate1 DATE,                  
 @ToDate1 DATE                   
)
AS
BEGIN 

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') is not null
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp
END

CREATE TABLE #Temp  
(                  
 @BranchID INT,                  
 @FromDate DATE,                    
 @ToDate DATE,                  
 @FromDate1 DATE,                  
 @ToDate1 DATE                   
)

Select                                
C.CustomerID, C.Name +' - '+c.ShortCode AS CustomerName, ShortCode, SUM(CAST(G.Total AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS FirstQtrBillingAmount
INTO #Temp

FROM GCNNC G with (NOLOCK)                               
JOIN Customer C ON C.CUSTOMERID=G.CUSTOMERID

where G.IsActive=1 AND C.CompanyID=1 AND (G.BranchID=@BranchID OR 0=@BranchID)                                        
AND                               
(CAST(G.Date AS DATE)>=@FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL) AND                               
(CAST(G.Date AS DATE)<=@ToDate  OR @ToDate  IS NULL)                              

group by C.CustomerID,C.Name +' - '+c.ShortCode, ShortCode
ORDER BY C.CustomerID

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') is not null
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Temp1
END

CREATE TABLE #Temp1 
(                  
 @BranchID INT,                  
 @FromDate DATE,                    
 @ToDate DATE,                  
 @FromDate1 DATE,                  
 @ToDate1 DATE                   
)

Select                                
C.CustomerID, C.Name +' - '+c.ShortCode AS CustomerName, ShortCode, SUM(CAST(G.Total AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS SecondQtrBillingAmount                  
INTO #Temp1

From GCNNC G with (NOLOCK)                               
JOIN Customer C ON C.CUSTOMERID=G.CUSTOMERID                   

where G.IsActive=1 AND C.CompanyID=1 AND (G.BranchID=@BranchID OR 0=@BranchID)                   
AND                               
(CAST(G.Date AS DATE)>=@FromDate1 OR @FromDate1 IS NULL) AND                               
(CAST(G.Date AS DATE)<=@ToDate1   OR @ToDate1   IS NULL)                              

group by C.CustomerID,C.Name +' - '+c.ShortCode, ShortCode                  
ORDER BY C.CustomerID 

SELECT                   
 CASE WHEN t1.CustomerID IS NULL THEN t2.CustomerID ELSE t1.CustomerID END AS CustomerID,                  
 CASE WHEN t1.CustomerName IS NULL THEN t2.CustomerName ELSE t1.CustomerName END AS CustomerName,                  
 CASE WHEN t1.ShortCode IS NULL THEN t2.ShortCode ELSE t1.ShortCode END AS ShortCode,                  
 Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) AS FirstQtrBillingAmount,Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) AS SecondQtrBillingAmount,                    
 Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)-Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) AS IncDecAmount,                   
 CASE                   
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) - Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0)=0 THEN CAST('0' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) <=0 THEN CAST('-100' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) <=0 THEN CAST('+100' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) >0 THEN CAST(((Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)-Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0)) / Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)) * 100  AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
 END AS IncDecPerc 

FROM #Temp t1                  
LEFT JOIN #Temp1 t2                  
ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID 

UNION 

SELECT                   
 CASE WHEN t1.CustomerID IS NULL THEN t2.CustomerID ELSE t1.CustomerID END AS CustomerID,                  
 CASE WHEN t1.CustomerName IS NULL THEN t2.CustomerName ELSE t1.CustomerName END AS CustomerName,               
 CASE WHEN t1.ShortCode IS NULL THEN t2.ShortCode ELSE t1.ShortCode END AS ShortCode,                  
 Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) AS FirstQtrBillingAmount,Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) AS SecondQtrBillingAmount,                    
 Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)-Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) AS IncDecAmount,                   
 CASE                   
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) - Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0)=0 THEN CAST('0' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) <=0 THEN CAST('-100' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0) <=0 THEN CAST('+100' AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
  WHEN Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0) >0 THEN CAST(((Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)-Coalesce(FirstQtrBillingAmount,0)) / Coalesce(SecondQtrBillingAmount,0)) * 100  AS DECIMAL(18,2))                  
END AS IncDecPerc                    

FROM #Temp t1                  
RIGHT JOIN #Temp1 t2                  
ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID                  

END
```

Comment: You cannot create temp table column name with "@prefixed". Thats y you are getting that error. It should be CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (
BranchID INT,FromDate DATE,...) Only for declaring variables u need "@prefixed" with variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I hope this will execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't run the stored procedure yet to debug but I think you need to remove the @ in front of the column names inside the temporary tables.

Instead of this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
@BranchID INT,
@FromDate DATE,
@ToDate DATE,
@FromDate1 DATE,
@ToDate1 DATE
)
```

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
BranchID INT,
FromDate DATE,
ToDate DATE,
FromDate1 DATE,
ToDate1 DATE
)
```

Do the same for #Temp1.